# How to use PHP link in video src link

Tags: php, html

I want to use a PHP link in the video src tag.

I have this video tag:

```html
<video controls>
<source src="phpcode.php" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
```

And I want PHP like this ( in this php : 'phpcode.php' ):

```
<?php

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){

/// myvideo.mp4 play this;

}else{

echo 'Cannot GET Video';

}
```

How do I do this? Is it possible?

Comment: phpcode.php is not a valid link to a video. PHP is also stateless and parses HTML before it is sent to the user. You either have to include the PHP file to include the correct link before or you need to use the PHP file as a web service that is addressed with a Methopde GET.

Comment: Start googling how to stream video using php, I doubt this has never been asked before

Comment: Also, is this your question as well, created from a different account: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76943160/load-video-link-to-html-player-with-php? Should we close one of the questions?