# Load video link to html player with php

Tags: php, html

I Have HTML video this tag for video play.................

```
 <video id="video-help" width="530" controls>
        <source id="videoPath" src="whatever.php?p=123" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

And i have this **whatever.php** file code ..

```
<?php

if($_GET['p']!='123'){

    die('Not Found');

}

$file = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=preview&id=1ym-pJX8yCMs6Sz1z-bwHuD4MIBwlOmAT";

if(!file_exists($file)) return; 

$fp = @fopen($file, 'rb');      
$size   = filesize($file); // File size 
$length = $size;           // Content length
$start  = 0;               // Start byte
$end    = $size - 1;       // End byte  
header('Content-type: video/mp4');
header("Accept-Ranges: 0-$length");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes"); 
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    $c_start = $start;              
    $c_end   = $end;                
    list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
    if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;      
    }              
    if ($range == '-') {            
        $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
    }else{         
        $range  = explode('-', $range); 
        $c_start = $range[0];           
        $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
    }
    $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
    if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) { 
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;      
    }
    $start  = $c_start;             
    $end    = $c_end;               
    $length = $end - $start + 1;    
    fseek($fp, $start);             
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
}                  
header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
header("Content-Length: ".$length);
$buffer = 1024 * 8;
while(!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end) { 
    if ($p + $buffer > $end) {      
        $buffer = $end - $p + 1;        
    }              
    set_time_limit(0);              
    echo fread($fp, $buffer);       
    ob_flush();    
}
fclose($fp);       
exit();


?>
```

This php code not working on video url  please solve my this problem ..............

I have been trying to make this since morning but I could not do it please solve this
This code works when we put video link of our host but I have to do it from other web link

Answer (score 3):

This here is your problem:

```
$file = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=preview&id=1ym-pJX8yCMs6Sz1z-bwHuD4MIBwlOmAT";

if(!file_exists($file)) return;
```

`file_exists` only checks for "local" files and is not able to check for files in URLs. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444059/file-exists-returns-false-for-remote-url) stackoverflow thread for how to deal with it!

Also worth mentioning:
For `fopen` to work with url make sure `allow_url_fopen` is set to true in your php.ini (By default it should be true). From the [official docs](https://www.php.net/manual/de/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen):

> allow_url_fopen bool: This option enables the URL-aware fopen wrappers
> that enable accessing URL object like files.

Comment: not working bro

Comment: Can you specify, what you have tried? Have you removed the file_exists line? Can you check the value of $fp (e.g if fopen is working)

Comment: @Sukrat first thing that happens when I request the URL you got there, in my browser, is that it _redirects_ me to the Google login mask. You are not providing any cookie or other credentials with your request, so I think you can hardly expect anything else to happen with your attempt to fetch this URL via PHP either. So in all likelihood, you did not _get_ the actual video data here in the first place.